# SignalR y dispositivos moviles

Tags: android, ios, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Buenas

Estaba utilizando signalr para actualizar una aplicación en la cual se muestran vehículos en movimiento sobre un mapa, la ubicaciones se notifican desde el server a la pagina mediante signalr, mientra la pagina esta activa, en el browser del dispositivo(no es una aplicacion hibrida), todo bien, pero si envío el browser a segundo plano, sin importar si es android o ios, o si la pc se suspende, el browser al reactivarse deja de recibir las notificaciones del server. trate con el evento connectionSlow o en error, y reconectar el cliente pero esto no funciono. alguna sugerencia?

```
//esta es la inicializacion de signalr
//Bus
    transit = $.connection.transit;
    transit.client.updateBus = updateBus;
    transit.client.initBuses = initBuses;
    $.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['serverSentEvents', 'foreverFrame'] }).done(function () {
            transit.server.init();
        });
        $.connection.hub.connectionSlow(function () {
            try {
                $.connection.hub.stop();
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            finally {
                $.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['serverSentEvents', 'foreverFrame'] }).done(function () { });
            }
        });
        $.connection.hub.error(function (error) {
            try {
                console.log(error);
                $.connection.hub.stop();
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            finally {
                $.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['serverSentEvents', 'foreverFrame'] }).done(function () { });
            }

        });
```

Comment: Agrega las partes esenciales de tu código.

Comment: estas usando apache cordova ?

Comment: Muchas gracias, no esta no es una app hibrida, es un site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recuerda que cuando estas en un device no existe el concepto de segundo plano, las aplicaciones se suspenden y reactivan, por lo general existen eventos que puedes usar para controlar esto.

Imagino estas usando `Apache Cordova`

[Apache Cordova Device Events](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html)

como veras cuando pones la aplicacion en segundo plano se deberia ejecutar el evento `pause` y al ponerla en primer plano el `resume`

Es en estos eventos donde deberias actualizar la conexion de signalr

Tambien podrias evaluar los eventos de reconect

[Understanding and Handling Connection Lifetime Events in SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events)

analiza el titulo "**How to continuously reconnect**"

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo que pasa es que esta no es una aplicación híbrida, es un site responsive,

Comment: entonces estas accediendo desde browser de los device ?

Comment: Si correcto desde el browser en los dispositivos

Comment: edite la respuesta agregando un link que creo podria ayudar en este caso